# Altair: two independent sliders for a layered plot

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I have a dataframe like this one ([code](https://pastebin.com/1rhgCqpy) to generate the data):
[image]

I want to compare two lines - `l1` and `l2`, both depend on the parameter `t`. Each line has five values of `t` sampled that are numbered with `t_i`. I want to plot both lines, with one of the sampled points highlighted for each line. The points to highlight should be set with two sliders - one for each line.

I can get it working without the sliders:

```python
base = alt.Chart(df).encode(x='x', y='y', color='line_name')
for line_name in df.line_name.unique():
  line = base.transform_filter(datum.line_name == line_name)
  plots += [line.mark_line(), line.mark_point().transform_filter(datum.t_i == int(line_name[1]))]
alt.layer(*plots)
```

Or with 1 slider:

```py
for line_name in df.line_name.unique():
  line = base.transform_filter(datum.line_name == line_name)
  slider = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=4, step=1, name='t_i:')
  select_t_i = alt.selection_single(name="t_i", fields=['t_i'], bind=slider, init={'t_i': 0})
  plots += [line.mark_line(), 
            line.mark_point().add_selection(select_t_i).transform_filter(select_t_i)]
alt.layer(*plots[:-1])
```

I get the expected result:

[image]

But if I change the last line to actually add the second slider:

```py
alt.layer(*plots[:-1]) -> alt.layer(*plots)
```

I get nothing - the plot does not show up and calling `display` does not help. How should I do that instead?

Also, I would like to see the value of `t` for the selected point, not the `t_i`. I actually added `t_i` because I couldn't define the slider with arbitrary values - all examples I saw, have `min, max, step`. How can I display the value of `t`, so it is updated with the slider?

Thanks!

**EDIT (working code):**

```py
for line_name in df.line_name.unique():
  line = base.transform_filter(datum.line_name == line_name)
  slider = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=4, step=1, name='t_%s:' % line_name[1:])
  select_t_i = alt.selection_single(fields=['t_i'], bind=slider, init={'t_i': 0})
  plots += [line.mark_line(), 
            line.mark_point().add_selection(select_t_i).transform_filter(select_t_i)]
alt.layer(*plots[:-1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two selections cannot have the same name. Remove `name="t_i"` from your selection definition (so that each one will have a unique automatically-generated name), and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jake! Your suggestion worked and I also watched your 2018 PyCon tutorial, so things are starting to make sense. I still have one issue though: if I make my line graph interactive then on every movement the selection resets and all the points from ``line.mark_point().add_selection(select_t_i).transform_filter(select_t_i)`` become visible, not just one. Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: I'd usually avoid filtering on a selection that's added to the same chart panel.